# Give email account to asp net membership user

Tags: asp.net, email, forms-authentication

Is it possible to give a user an email address on the local machine when they signup for an account with asp net forms authentication.

So say bob signs up on the website "foo.com" can i give him an email address like "bob@foo.com".

The account will only be accessed by the program and does not need a GUI.

Comment: Yes but not straight forward you can use ActiveX controls plus user will need admin rights on the machine they are using and allow the execution. So possible ? Yes ..Recommended ? No !! would be a huge failure of a system IMHO!!

Answer (score 0):

If a user provides their unique name and  password when signing, you can use the API for whatever mail server software you are running to create an email account for them.
ActiveX and Admin rights have nothing to do with this process.